# What is this type of digits-only LCD called?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, lcd, interface, display

I've seen this type of LCD many times in weigh scales, calculators, gauges, micrometers, etc. I know it's a fairly traditional display but I really like its compactness, simplicity, and maybe it even costs less, versus TFTs or smartphone-type touch displays.

[image: Digits-only LCD]

[**What is it called?** Answered by @kevlar1818 and @stevenvh: "Seven-segment display"]

I would like to work with this type of LCD, for example, I just found this 8-digit one called VIM-878  from the Digikey catalog; here is [its datasheet](http://www.varitronix.com/prod_pdf/VIM-878.pdf).

**How do I interface with it?** I would like to know what would be a good/common way of interfacing with it from a simple AVR microcontroller like an Atmega8 -- preferably with interfacing circuitry/parts that aren't too physically large.

- I presume some sort of driver or multiplexer would be necessary? I guess I'm looking for some beginning perspective from others who may have better experience interfacing with this type of LCD.

Comment: Thank you for adding the requested information. Please be careful that you don't undo previous edits in the process, however.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, didn't I, oops! Could you or someone help put the image back please?

Comment: You could try rolling back to edit 2, and then adding your information to that. I don't have the rep to do rollbacks so I'll flag it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a **7-segments display**. Unlike the **dot-matrix character displays** *kevlar* refers to these are most often not intelligent module. Most dot matrix displays have an HD44780-compatible controller which you simply can write ASCII codes to, but a 7-segment LCD will often be just the glass, with connections for segments and a number of backplanes (often up to 4).

[image]

Driving LCDs can be awkward since they don't use just two levels, so you can't drive them with common digital logic.

[image]

The best thing you can do is select a microcontroller with integrated LCD controller, which you can connect the display directly to, like the TI [MSP430x4xx](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f412.pdf). Like most controllers this one also knows just segments; it isn't aware of digits or anything. (Great, first we had a dumb display, now we have a dumb driver as well!) There's reason for this. These LCD drivers are often used to drive custom LCDs which may be a mix of a numeric part, bar graphs and custom symbols. Such a symbol is also a single segment, so it makes no sense to talk about digits.

[image]

This display has symbols like "battery" and "alarm clock", but also all text fields, like "AM", "PM" and "SNOOZE" are symbols consisting of a single segment (i.e. controlled by a single bit).

**Further reading**
[MSP430x4xx Family User's Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau056j/slau056j.pdf). LCD controller is covered on p.709 ff.

Comment: Assuming segments mean the number of parts used to construct a character/digit on my LCD, I think that microcontroller would be great - it can support 96, and it has only 200 uA current draw. Are you suggesting replacing my AVR with the TI microcontroller, or just communicating VIA it with the LCD? I'd prefer the latter, because of my AVR-based experience (also limited!); so can you comment on that?

Comment: @Inga - I'm not aware of any AVR with an LCD driver on board. Using the MSP430 as display driver may be a good idea: your AVR can stick to its main task, and the program for the MSP430 can be kept simple (if you don't have much experience with it) or advanced (if you want to make it an intelligent driver, which you can supply with commands like "increment").

Comment: That sounds very doable; I'm about to order one of the TI chips! By the way, in case my programming attempts with that microcontroller fail, can I use a simple multiplexer or LED driver, e.g. an IC like [this one I just found from Maxim](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1339) ? I am foreseeing trouble because of what you stated about the multiple levels.

Comment: @Inga - No, you can't use the MAX7219, that's a LED driver. For one thing they multiplex much too fast for LCDs. The multiple levels shouldn't be a problem; that's what you've got a driver for. That takes care of everything. What do you think of the intelligent driver which keeps count of the number to display? You could use commands like "load value", "increment count", "reset count", etc.

Comment: Haha, it really has commands like that?! I surely have to write code to implement those functions myself, don't I?

Comment: @Inga - Yes, you'll have to write them yourself; the LCD driver only knows segments, they don't even have to be numeric. Many custom LCDs have symbols as a single segment. But it could take a load from the AVR, and you could re-use it for other projects where you need a numeric display.

Comment: Got it, so [LCD lights requested segments ON] <<--- [MSP430's code runs a function I write to translate UART-received characters into segments that are driven ON/OFF] <<--- [AVR's code sends desired text to MSP430 via UART].

Comment: One note: when you said the LCD driver only "knows" segments (and the multiple levels are taken care of by it); what does that mean? How do I take advantage of this feature when I code the TI chip/driver? I'm starting to read the datasheet, but am I missing something?

Comment: I have found this [reference/User's guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau056j/slau056j.pdf) for that microcontroller/driver: Chapter 25 deals with the LCD control in detail. Perhaps you can add this to your answer, if that is possible or of interest.

Comment: @Inga - Yes, I was about to point you to the user's guide; the datasheet doesn't give you details. The user guide has programming examples as well. You'll see that the display is represented as an array of 16 bytes. It's up to you to decide what each bit represents: a segment of a 7-digit display, or a symbol on a custom display, for instance.

Comment: A decade ago in one of my electronics labs I used a 4(?) digit 7-segment display that had separate input pins for each digit and which was controlled with simple digital logic, so muxing and controller chips aren't isn't strictly required.  The module was rather expensive though; IIRC >$100.

Comment: @Dan - You can do that if you don't need/want multiplexing. The drawback is that you need a lot more I/Os: 33 for a 4 digit + decimal points display (4 x 8 + 1 common).

Answer (score 2):

A [seven-segment display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display) or [dot matrix display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_matrix_display) are what you're referring to I believe.

Here's an example on [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/255) with the relevant [datasheet](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf). Found this [AVR example/tutorial](http://homepage.hispeed.ch/peterfleury/avr-lcd44780.html) in the "Documents" section of the product page. Isn't Sparkfun great?

---

Given [this 14-segment display](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/VIM-878-DP-RC-S-HV/153-1114-ND/1118604), and its [datasheet](http://www.varitronix.com/prod_pdf/VIM-878.pdf), let's figure out how to use it.

Let's take the example of showing a `7` in the first (leftmost) segment cluster.

To write a `7`, we need to assert segments `1A`, `1B`, and `1C`, as seen in the datasheet. These segments all map to pin 35 of the device, but on different `COM` lines. With such a cryptic datasheet, my best guess would be that these `COM` lines map to pins 17 through 20, given the table in the datasheet.

Thus, to assert each segment above, you would hold pin 35 high while quickly cycling between asserting `COM1`, `COM2`, and `COM3` via pins 18, 19, and 20 respectively. The three segments would all appear lit simultaneously, creating a `7`.

This being said, well-written code simply will use some sort of map for any given character to be displayed. The challenge is to make this map work for ANY of the segment clusters.

---

I still recommend a dot-matrix display like the first one I linked to; there are certainly more lightweight designs out there. The benefit to using a dot-matrix display is that most have a data register built-in, so you can just pass it 8-bit ASCII characters, no funky implementation issues like in the 14-seg example above.

Comment: Incidentally, I have an LCD very similar to the example you posted! But it is a very thick module and it isn't very readable without its backlight on. Whereas the one I posted is visible much better despite no backlight, and somehow seems cleaner (no shadowy-remnant-type of appearance of the non-displayed digits). Any thoughts? Are there sub-categories within these displays?

Comment: Using "seven-segment display" as my search term, I found this one: [Digikey page](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/VIM-878-DP-RC-S-HV/153-1114-ND/1118604) I would like to work with this one, for example. And this is [its datasheet](http://www.varitronix.com/prod_pdf/VIM-878.pdf).

Comment: I was actually going to say (based on your explanation) that the 14-segment one seems SIMPLER, no? Well, OK, not simpler than just passing ASCII characters, but fairly simple in terms of logic and the amount of control (e.g., just lighting up one segment). BTW, in the approach you recommended above, how does it deal with what stevenvh said in his Answer about there not being two levels of logic for these displays?

Comment: @Inga It doesn't seem to me like there would need to be more than two logic levels in this particular 14-segment display, as it has such a verbose pinout. I'm still not positive though, because the datasheet and Digikey page say nothing about voltage/logic levels. Honestly, it's usually not good practice to buy such a poorly documented device.

Comment: Oy, it is poorly documented, isn't it! :( May I ask you to recommend a model or even just a company where I should source this type of display but with better documentation, if I want to stick with learning to code the 7-segment display the way you introduced above?

Comment: @Inga I have no recommendations for 7-seg displays, really; I still think you should find a good dot-matrix display. I'd just keep looking on Digikey and Sparkfun until you find one with good documentation and something that meets your specs.

Comment: Why not use some of the LCD drivers, that interface over I2C, such as Holtek 1632 or similar? (I hope I got the part correct!)

Answer (score 2):

What you are thinking of is called a 7 segment LCD. If you know how to light up a regular LED then your 1/8th of the way there.

Here is the Wiki to it. It has some theory on how you would create numbers by lighting up different arrays of the LED's:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display

(de)Multiplexing is a good method for lighting up a large 7-Segment panel, although not necessary. If your I/O ports are limited then it's the way to go. The basic's of demuxing work like this (assuming you know binary here). Look at this picture:[image]

With a 3 bit binary number like 000 we can represent up to the number 7 (I.E. to select port 5 we'd have ABC be 101). What would happen in the demux in your situation is one input is something like a high signal, and AB&C are I/O ports. The 0 to 7 are connect to each segment of the LCD and by writing to ABC from your controller you can light up a segment. You may be saying wait but if I want to light up a number I need many segments lit, not just the 5th segment. Well after that you can look into two roads to get the LCD to display a number. The first is add more demux's for additional needed segments. The second is a software approach which involves very very quickly flashing each of the segment required to create the illusion that the panel is completely lit. The AVR chip in your mega is operating in the Megahertz range if you write a loop to display ABGED (from the wiki pic) you will end up seeing something that looks like a number 2. Hope this gets you started.

Comment: I like the first approach that you suggested: more demux's. But if I were to go that route, how can one cut down on physical size of components? In my case, I would need 8 digits = 56 segments, you know?

Comment: Err well you're not going to have enough I/0 to drive 8 digits with a nothing but hardware approach. Here is a link, it's scary I know but I don't think I can draw/explain an easier breakdown. http://www.doctronics.co.uk/4511.htm. That's the theory though. In practicality I would consider the scanning method, I know it may seem like it would not provide a nice image or would be complicated but it's a very common practice in industry. Best of luck.

Comment: @Inga - even 64 if you also count decimal points! There are two reasons you won't find those non-multiplexed. One is just the sheer number of pins, both on the display and the microcontroller. The microcontroller would need at least 80 pins and more pins = more cost. But there's also routing. If you have a multiplexed display you will have the routing of one segment going via an adjacent segment, but if they're all separate you can't do a thing like that. That's also an extra cost.